# logstash file input failing to read file

Tags: linux, file, chef-infra, logstash

I've been scratching my head over this for hours, and I'm getting kind of frustrated. I'm new to logstash, so I might be doing something wrong, but after a few hours working on this, I can't figure out what. I configured both **agent** and **server** using the **[chef-logstash cookbook](https://github.com/lusis/chef-logstash)**.

I have two system that I've set up, an **agent** and a **server**. The **agent** reads files, filters them, then ships them off to the redis instance on the **server**. The **server** grabs incoming entries from redis, and indexes them in elasticsearch (using *embedded*).

Here's my problem, I can use a simple config like the one below, enter input to the **server**, and everything ships off to the **server**, just fine.

```
input { stdin { } }
output {
  redis {
    host => "192.168.33.11"
    data_type => "list"
    key => "logstash"
    codec => json
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Everything get's picked up properly by the logstash running on my **server** (in vagrant), they get indexed, and I can see them in Kibana.

The **agent** is another story. On my agent, started with 3 config files, `input_file_nginx.conf`, `output_stdout.conf`, `output_redis.conf`. I found that the logs weren't getting to my redis on my **server**, so I tried to narrow it down. It was when I looked at my logs on my **agent** I got really confused. As far as I could tell, nothing was getting read. Either that, or my `output_stdout.conf` is messed up.

Here's my `input_file_nginx.conf`

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/home/silkstart/logs/*.log"
    type => "nginx"
  }
}
```

For reference, the two files in there are `nginx.silkstart.80.access.log` and `nginx.silkstart.80.error.log`, which both have `644` permissions, so should be readable.

And my `output_stdout.conf`

```
output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

These were all generated using `logstash_config` from some erbs.

My instance came almost verbatim from the `agent.rb` example

```
logstash_service name do
  action    [:enable]
  method    "runit"
end
```

Here's the resulting config

```
#!/bin/sh

cd //opt/logstash/agent
exec 2>&1
# Need to set LOGSTASH_HOME and HOME so sincedb will work
LOGSTASH_HOME="/opt/logstash/agent"
GC_OPTS=""
JAVA_OPTS="-server -Xms198M -Xmx596M -Djava.io.tmpdir=$LOGSTASH_HOME/tmp/  "
LOGSTASH_OPTS="agent -f $LOGSTASH_HOME/etc/conf.d"
LOGSTASH_OPTS="$LOGSTASH_OPTS --pluginpath $LOGSTASH_HOME/lib"
LOGSTASH_OPTS="$LOGSTASH_OPTS -vv"
LOGSTASH_OPTS="$LOGSTASH_OPTS -l $LOGSTASH_HOME/log/logstash.log"
export LOGSTASH_OPTS="$LOGSTASH_OPTS -w 1"
HOME=$LOGSTASH_HOME exec chpst -u logstash:logstash $LOGSTASH_HOME/bin/logstash $LOGSTASH_OPTS
```

This is fairly similar to my **server** config, which works

```
#!/bin/sh

ulimit -Hn 65550
ulimit -Sn 65550

cd //opt/logstash/server
exec 2>&1
# Need to set LOGSTASH_HOME and HOME so sincedb will work
LOGSTASH_HOME="/opt/logstash/server"
GC_OPTS=""
JAVA_OPTS="-server -Xms1024M -Xmx218M -Djava.io.tmpdir=$LOGSTASH_HOME/tmp/  "
LOGSTASH_OPTS="agent -f $LOGSTASH_HOME/etc/conf.d"
LOGSTASH_OPTS="$LOGSTASH_OPTS --pluginpath $LOGSTASH_HOME/lib"
LOGSTASH_OPTS="$LOGSTASH_OPTS -l $LOGSTASH_HOME/log/logstash.log"
export LOGSTASH_OPTS="$LOGSTASH_OPTS -w 1"
HOME=$LOGSTASH_HOME exec chpst -u logstash:logstash $LOGSTASH_HOME/bin/logstash $LOGSTASH_OPTS
```

The only difference I can see here is

```
ulimit -Hn 65550
ulimit -Sn 65550
```

but I don't see why that should stop that from working. This would increase the number of file descriptors, but the default 4096 should be plenty.

When make some requests to the server to make sure the log has new stuff, and I check the runit logs, it only points me to `/opt/logstash/agent/log/logstash.log`, which I have pasted the contents of at https://gist.github.com/jrstarke/384f192abdd93c0acf2a.

To really throw a wrench in things, if I `sudo su logstash` and run `bin/logstash -f etc/conf.d` from the command line, everything works as expected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This seems ServerFault question seems related http://serverfault.com/questions/527706/logstash-cant-read-files-it-should-have-access-too

Answer (score 2):

I managed to figure this out. For anyone else that's facing a similar issue, you will want to check your permissions on the files you're trying to access.

If you're accessing files that you have access to through group permissions, you're likely facing the same issue I did.

Look closely at this line

`exec chpst -u logstash:logstash`

That this tells us is that we want to run a program as user logstash, with the group permissions logstash. In my case, the group that I wanted to use was an additional group. The docs for chpst note that

> If group consists of a colon-separated list of group names, chpst sets the group ids of all listed groups.

So if I wanted to run the program as `user1` with both `group1` and `group2`, that command would become

`exec chpst -u user1:group1:group2`

I hope this helps anyone else that is running into the same issue I did.